# Sitecore Log Viewer: Application access denied for all users including admin after upgrade

Tags: security, upgrade

I'm getting a `Sitecore.Exceptions.AccessDeniedException: Application access denied.` exception when opening the Log Viewer, even though my user is Administrator. I have upgraded the project from 7.2 to 8.2 using the Express Migration Tool.

I am getting this error:

[image]

According to the Access Viewer and as expected for the Admin user, the user have access to the application in the Core DB:

[image]

I have checked folder security, which is set to full control, and the error indicates a Sitecore Security deny. 
I can't figure out why access is denied. Any tips or pointers where to look ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally found the root of this problem. Some how the Core database was missing random items after the migration. Not sure what happened, but started to compare items in Core, and found some items missing.The Log Viewer was dependent on these items and this caused this error.

I re-ran the migration to get a new migrated Core database, and nothing was missing this time.